# Mac OS binding to Samba PDC

Tags: mac, smb

Does anyone join a Mac OS to Samba PDC?

My point is to build a single domain for different clients (win xp, win 7, mac os 10.6) with home folders and roaming profiles.

I see 2 posible solutions:
1. Win binds to Samba PDC, Mac binds to OpenLDAP. In this case, OpenLDAP requires some schemas (see down this topic). And i don't know how to manage this.
2. All clients bind to Samba Domain. Mac client thinks it join to AD, and doesn't need something else. As i found, mac requires Kerberos.

I've installed Ubuntu Server 10.04 + OpenLDAP + Samba PDC + Gosa (for managment). It works fine with windows clients, but macintosh machines don't want to bind for some reasons:
1. Binding to OpenLDAD. It requires some apple schemes. When i try to add converted schemas from mac os (/etc/openldap/schema/apple.schema) it says i haven't necessary objectClasses. As i understood it needs apple samba schema, but i have already installed own schemes.
2. Binding to Samba PDC as AD 
It requires Kerberos. In this case i don't know what should i do? How should i install it: as a backend for samba, where should i hold principal base, etc...?

ps: Own mac os x 10.6 server works fine with mac clients through Open Directory (OpenLDAP variant). But win clients with Samba don't work for some reasons...

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 8 of Apple's [Open Directory Admin 10.6](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1180/en_US/OpenDirAdmin_v10.6.pdf) manual describes in great detail the operations you wish to complete. Also, skimming the table of contents for the word "bind" will also reveal information useful to you. Further, the [dsconfigad](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/dsconfigad.8.html) man page will also help you accomplish your goal. There are easy instructions on how to use dsconfigad [here](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/mac-os-x/9780321591067/configuring-mac-os-x-to-log-in-using-active-directory/ch04lev2sec9). You can also achieve what you are attempting using the Directory Utility in your /Applications/Utilities folder. There are easy instructions on how to use the Directory Utility [here](http://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-join-a-mac-os-x-computer-to-active-directory/), and it lists the prerequisites each Mac needs to bind to such a network. Also, flushing the DNS cache might do the trick:

```
 dscacheutil -flushcache
```